# Django graphene performance issue not related to the db but to the rendering

Tags: django, graphene-django

In Sentry APM I am able to see that most of the time spent was in the `view.render` I am assuming that this part is where the result from the db are being formatted but can't understand why it is taking a lot of time:
[image]

Comment: You should show us some code. Right? How else someone would understand the problems inside view.render with a picture?